# clojure slurp requires absolute path

Tags: clojure

Total noob to clojure - using slurp is not working when I try to read in a file that is in the same folder as the .clj file, unless I put the full absolute path.

E.G. if I have stuff/file.clj and stuff/words.txt, (slurp "words.txt") cannot find the file.  If i put the entire path, it works.  Based on reading other people's code and the documentation, this should  not be the case.

I am just running this scripts one-off without creating any sort of folder/projet structure which would be typical of a clojure application, so not sure if that causes any path issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slurp` takes paths relative to the current working directory, not the clojure file it's in. In a Clojure project this will usually be the project root (ie, the place where project.clj lives). But since you say you are just running standalone Clojure files without a project, it should be your shell's working directory.

Comment: Hmmm... must be that sublimerepl is executing from wherever clojure lives rather than the current working directory.  I'm use to build commands being path aware so that if you build a file in a directory, the shell calls the interpreter with that path.

Comment: Sounds like a problem related to your use of sublimerepl. You can find out what the JVM thinks the working directory is, by running `(System/getProperty "user.dir")`.

Comment: yep.... defaulting to sublimes location, need to figure out how to set it to the active directory.  Thx.